# Combinatorial with k subsets of n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a set $S$ with $k$ disjoint subsets $S_{i}$, i need to take a set $v$ of $k$ elements from $S$ in this way:

when $i=1$, $v_{1}$ can be taken from the whole set $S$.

When $i=2$, $v_{2}$ $\in$ $S \setminus S_{1}$

At $i=3$, $v_{3}$ $\in S \setminus (S_{1} \cup S_{2})$

for any generic $2\le i \le k$, $v_{i} \in S \setminus S_{1} \cup ... \cup S_{i-1}$

How many different $v$ will i obtain? supposing that $|S| = n$ and $|v|=k$

A small example to clarify this rule: 
let's say i have $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$
and $S_{1}=\{1,2,3\},S_{2}=\{4,5,6\}, S_{3}=\{7\}$, with $k=3$, $v=\{1,4,7\}$ is valid because $\{1\}∈S_{1},\{2\}∈S_{2}, \{7\} \in S_{3}$. Also $v=\{4,5,7\}$ is valid because 4,5 both are in $S_{2}$, but $v=\{1,2,7\}$ is NOT valid because i can take only 1 element from $S_{1}$

Comment: So, you have $k$ disjoint subsets, of different size, and you want to make a set  with $k$ elements, each taken from a different sub-set. Right?

Comment: only in part, for example i can take 2 elements from $S_{2}$ but only in position 1 or 2, while if these elements came both from the same sub-set order is not important. We can suppose that the disjoint sub-sets are all of the same size

Comment: that's not clear to me. better you put small example of your composition rule

Comment: Let's say i have $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $S_{1}=\{1,2,3\}, S_{2}=\{4,5,6\}$, with $k=2$,  $v=\{1,4\}$ is valid because $\{1\} \in S_{1}, \{2\} \in S_{2}$. Also $v = \{4,5\}$ is valid because they both are in $S_{2}$, but $v=\{1,2\}$ is not valid because i can take only 1 element from $S_{1}$